# Cypress says the command is too long to execute

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

There is a Cypress project with 250 test cases and it was working fine with bulk execution with tags or individual feature files. All of a sudden when executing the entire suite, it started to throw the error like "the command is too long" (refer the below screenshot for more console information.)

Later tried with a temporary solution to rename and reduce the length of the feature files and it started to work well with the test suite.
**Example: LoadQuantity to LoadQty**

But in a longer run, we would be adding more test cases and this temporary rename solution would not support. Do we have any best approach to solve this issue or missing any settings/attribute/flags here?

Appreciate all your suggestions and thoughts.

**cypress.json**

```
{
   "testFiles":"features/**/**/*.feature",
   "viewportWidth":1920,
   "viewportHeight":1080,
   "supportFile":"./cypress/support/index.ts",
   "chromeWebSecurity":false,
   "watchForFileChanges":false,
   "defaultCommandTimeout":20000,
   "taskTimeout":300000,
   "baseUrl":"https://test.com"
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
   "name":"Project",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "description":"Cypress project",
   "main":"index",
   "typings":"index",
   "scripts":{
      "qa":"npx cypress run --env configFile=qa",
      "stg":"npx cypress run --env configFile=stg",
      "stg2":"npx cypress run --env configFile=stg2",
      "runTests":"npx cypress run --browser chrome --env configFile=stg2 allure=true,allureResultsPath=reports/allure-results",
      "allureReport:generate":"allure generate ./reports/allure-results --clean -o ./reports/allure-report",
      "allureReport:clean":"if exist reports\\allure-results rmdir /q /s reports\\allure-results && if exist reports\\allure-report rmdir /q /s reports\\allure-report && if exist cypress\\screenshots rmdir /q /s cypress\\screenshots && if exist cypress\\videos rmdir /q /s cypress\\videos",
      "pretest":"npm run allureReport:clean",
      "test":"npx cypress-tags run TAGS=\"@smoke\" --env configFile=stg2 --browser chrome --headed || npm run posttest",
      "test:runAll":"npm run runTests || npm run posttest",
      "posttest":"npm run allureReport:generate"
   },
   "author":"",
   "license":"ISC",
   "devDependencies":{
      "@4tw/cypress-drag-drop":"^2.0.0",
      "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor":"^5.9.1",
      "@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin":"^2.19.5",
      "@types/node":"^16.9.0",
      "allure-commandline":"^2.13.8",
      "cypress":"^8.5.0",
      "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor":"^4.2.0",
      "cypress-plugin-tab":"^1.0.5",
      "cypress-sql-server":"^1.0.0",
      "cypress-xpath":"^1.6.2",
      "fs-extra":"^10.0.0",
      "mssql":"^7.2.1",
      "mysql2":"^2.3.0",
      "tsify":"^5.0.4",
      "typescript":"^4.4.2"
   },
   "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor":{
      "nonGlobalStepDefinitions":false
   }
}
```

Is there a way to increase the command line string length via Cypress CLI or any